# Can second parameter of Expression.Property be made dynamic?

Tags: linq, tree, expression

I'm working on a rule engine where we're transforming xml into code which gets compiled at runtime. And for this, we would like to access a property inside an object/collection which is not available as a string but rather as an expression.

A simplified example - a Student class with property Age

```
Expression stud = Expression.Variable(typeof(Student), "student");
Expression.Property(stud, Expression.Constant("Age"));
```

Comment: Do you know the type of the property, or a typeless result would be fine?

Comment: Type of the property can be any of the CTS defined types. For simplicity, I've kept the Age property as a constant expression. In reality it'll be a derived expression which holds 'Age' in its value..

Comment: Please give an example of your input (an xml?) and your desired output (an expression tree), so we can try to provide some code...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be something like this:

```
// represents a variable student
var studentExpression = Expression.Variable(typeof(Student), "student");

// represents student.Age
var studenDotAgeExpression = Expression.Property(studentExpression, typeof(Student).GetProperty("Age"));
```